# Can I use Javascript to send http request to a specific IP address?

Tags: javascript, http

I wonder if it is possible in Javascript to send HTTP GET request to a specific IP address? For example, with curl in Linux I can do this: `curl google.com --connect-to ::123.123.123.123`.

Sorry I did not mention, I meant to run the Javascript in a browser. That is, when a Javascript is loaded in a browser, is there a way to let the browser shot a HTTP request to a specific IP address?

Comment: you can use fetch for that. fetch("your_url_for_get_request")

Comment: Have a look at this resource https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: Depends on whether you want to run the javascript in a browser, or in node.js. The latter certainly can do anything without restrictions.

Comment: I knew fetch() can be used for url, but I did not find any resources saying I can insert an IP address there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you have webserver set up on that machine, then you can do this:

```
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     // do with the return value
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://123.123.123.123", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

If you don't have webserver set up, then your GET request would get error msg.

Comment: What do you mean by "webserver set up on that machine"? In your code, how would a host:google.com header be included such that the origin server knows to which host the request will be routed?

Comment: @mvvei01 Seems you have multiple host on a single IP? If so the host is required so  you can not send request to IP directly.